# Lubuntu and swap partition

Tags: lubuntu

Do I need a swap partition on Lubuntu too? Or is it only recommended for Ubuntu? I was wondering why we need swap in the 1st place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lubuntu and Ubuntu are basically no different in the execution of the OS. They are differently when it comes to GUI and applications.

Swap space is the area on a hard disk which is part of the Virtual Memory of your machine, which is a combination of accessible physical memory (RAM) and the swap space. Swap space temporarily holds memory pages that are inactive. Swap space is used when your system decides that it needs physical memory for active processes and there is insufficient unused physical memory available.

You should use a Swap partition.

Here is a ref for you https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

Comment: All Linux operating systems need swap space. As blueXrider states, the swap partition is virtual memory.

Answer (score 2):

simply NOT true.
Especially Lubuntu is made for staying lean. If your machine doesn't load everything at boot time and you've got the typival 2GBs of ram, a swap is necessary like a fifth wheel on a car.
Even Win XP Pro doesn't need a swap.
I've got abaout 200 mb ram used on lubuntu saucy salamander and about the same for xp AFTER
managing to disable all unwanted start-at-boottime-files, overdone Browser-cache, etc.
It also keeps SSDs Lifetime longer, as there's (almost) no unnecessesary write procedures.

Only thing, which makes my laptops freeze is unwanted js-code from some websites.(sometimes, when I forget to turn js off in Browser-Options). But thats got nothing to do with swap or ram.

Comment: I would say @ringtail 's chosen answer above is the canonical answer, but here Ascervera's answer is a practical answer. It is true that you are supposed to have swap/virtual memory, but if your usage pattern does not actually use them, you are fine for not having swap. Personally I used Win XP before, it also used a pagefile (a.k.a. the "swap" in the Windows term) by default, but I disabled it and I'm fine as long as my ram consumption stays under the physical memory amount. Now I use Lubuntu boot flash disk frequently, and it just works without any swap.